# Skip directory which exists in delete loop

Tags: android, directory, subdirectory

Found a nice code to delete a directory including subdirs but is it possible to implement that a (sub)directory which for example exists (.data) is not being deleted?

Thanks for the help.

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
        return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: Means you do not want to delete those subdirectories which contains "." as prefix ? Please clarify!!

Comment: @Deep Mehta
Yes, exactly that, for instance .data should be preserved the rest deleted including subdirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            if(children[i].equals("data")||children[i].equals(".data"))
                continue;
            else
                if (!deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]))) 
                    return false;
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            if(children.equals("data")){
              boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
              if (!success) {
                return false;
              }
           }
    }
}
    return dir.delete();
```

}